# React-Native/Redux Error: Requested keys of a value that is not an object

Tags: react-native, react-redux

On running the below code, i end up with the error message "Requested keys of a value that is not an object" in CategoryList.js.

I believe "stores.dispatch(CategoryAction.categoryView())" in CategoryContainer.js  should set the value to props category, but  this.props.categories in CategoryList.js returns null value which causes the error.

ConfigureStore.js:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import reducers from '../reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);
export default store;
```

CategoryContainer.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import stores from '../stores/ConfigureStore';
import * as CategoryAction from '../actions/CategoryAction';

stores.dispatch(CategoryAction.categoryView());

class CategoryContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <CategoryList/>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    categories: state.categories,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    bindActionCreators(CategoryAction, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CategoryContainer);
```

CategoryAction.js:

```
import * as actionTypes from './ActionTypes';
import AppConstants from '../constants/AppConstants';

export function categoryView() {
  const categories = [{name:'CATEGORY', type:'CATGORY_TYPE'}];
  return {
      type: "CATEGORY_VIEW",
      categories: categories
  };
}
```

CategoryReducer.js:

```
const initialState = {
  categories:[]
}

export default function categoryReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CATEGORY_VIEW":
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
              categories: action.categories
            });
    }
}
```

CategoryList.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Text, View, TouchableHighlight, TouchableOpacity, ListView, StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

import * as AppConstants from '../constants/AppConstants';
import CategoryAdd from '../components/CategoryAdd';

export default class CategoryList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2})
    this.state = {
      dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.categories),
    }
  }
}
```

I even tried as below in CategoryContainer.js, but it doesn't help. Still got the same error,

```
<CategoryList {...this.props}/>
```

But if i change the CategoryList.js by replacing this.props.categories with constant value as below, it works.

```
    const categories = [{name:'CATEGORY', type:'CATGORY_TYPE'}];
    this.state = {
      dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRows(categories),
    }
```

Kindly assist to set values in this.props.categories on redux flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below changes in CategoryContainer.js makes it works,

```
    categories: state.categoryReducer.categories,
    modal: state.categoryReducer.modal
```

Answer (score 1):

You should update the `categories` array in reducer like this -

```
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    categories: Object.assign([], state.categories, action.categories)
  });
```

And then do `<CategoryList {...this.props}/>` in container.

Comment: I tried the suggested solution, but still getting the same error. Not sure where i am wrong.